# Как сгенерировать массив в Javascript из входящих переменных?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть html код с тегом script, куда я отправляю данные:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js" class="33.870959 -118.027830 33.803498 -118.279524 34.087291 -118.259329"></script>
```

Вот собственно сам Javascript:

```
function initMap() 
{  var center = {lat: 34.046438, lng: -118.259653};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: center
  });
var params = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script');
query = params[0].classList;

var locations = [
    ['hwlo',   query[0], query[1]],
    ['hwlo',   query[2], query[3]],
    ['hwlo',   query[4], query[5]],
  ];

var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
var marker, count;
for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]),
      map: map,
      title: document.currentScript.getAttribute('one')
    });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, count) {
      return function () {
        infowindow.setContent(document.currentScript.getAttribute('one'));
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, count));
  }
}
```

Вот код, который забирает данные из html:

```
var params = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script');
query = params[0].classList;

var locations = [
    ['hwlo',   query[0], query[1]],
    ['hwlo',   query[2], query[3]],
    ['hwlo',   query[4], query[5]],
  ];
```

Я хочу, чтобы массив locations генерировался автоматически, в зависимости от того, сколько переменных пришло из html - "33.870959 -118.027830 33.803498 -118.279524 34.087291 -118.259329". Этих данных может быть либо больше, либо меньше.
В языке Java не очень разбираюсь, поэтому вопрос немного дилетантский.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно заменить

```
var locations = [
    ['hwlo',   query[0], query[1]],
    ['hwlo',   query[2], query[3]],
    ['hwlo',   query[4], query[5]],
  ];
```

на

```
var locations = [];
for(var i = 0; i < query.length; i = i + 2) {
    locations.push([
        'hwlo', query[i], query[i + 1]
    ]);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, работает